# Small TCP Window When Running Spring Batch Application

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am running a Spring Batch application from Spring Boot that talks to a DB2 database. The application takes incoming flat test files, parses them and stores the data in work tables for transformation and then another set of tables for another application to consume.

When the application is executing it is advertising a TCP Window Size of ~500B or less consistently. The database advertises 65k. Is there something in Spring Boot or Spring Batch that would drop the advertised TCP Window size that small? We have looked at the servers and don't see any misconfiguration.

The application is running on Oracle JDK 8, Spring Boot 1.3.2, Spring Batch 3.0.6 and DB2 10.5.6. The database is AIX and the Spring app is on RHEL.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the TCP Window Size used by the JDBC connection and we don't do anything to that.

Comment: I didn't think you did but I wanted to make sure. I had pulled the source for Batch and Boot and did some grepping to see if I could find anything and wasn't able to get any matches.  And yes, I was referring to the TCP Window Size used by the JDBC connection. Thanks for the confirmation.